# Autocomplete событие select

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Добрый день!

Использую виджет автокомплете и подключаю к нескольким `input`

JQuery:

```
 $("input[id^='reis_owner_id']").autocomplete({
   source: "library/_ajax_profile.php?get_autocomplete_owner_for_contract",
   minLength: 3,
   select: function(event, ui) {},
   search: function() {
     $(this).addClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
   },
   open: function(event, ui) {
     $(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
     $("#ui-id-1").css("left", parseInt($("#ui-id-1").css("left")) + "px");

   }
 })
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="reis_owner_id123" class="input_guide ui-autocomplete-input" value="Вася" />

<input type="text" id="reis_owner_id01234" class="input_guide ui-autocomplete-input" value="Вася" />
```

Ну и т.д., то есть я по фильтру подключаю автокомплект ко всем `input`
у которых `id` начинается с `reis_owner_id`.
Как узнать в событии `select`, с каким `input` сейчас работает виджет?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `$(this)`

Например, можно узнать конкретное id - `$(this).attr('id')`. В вашем случае можно этот id передать на сервер и там обработать

```
   source: "library/_ajax_profile.php?get_autocomplete_owner_for_contract&id=" + $(this).attr('id')
```

Answer (score -1):

Проблема была в том, что `$(this)` возвращал не элемент, а объект с которым работал плагин.

Comment: Распишите своё решение более детально, что бы пользователи могли понять в чём была проблема